# My poll command isn't working in discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My code is not giving me any errors. However, it is not working:

```js
client.on('message', async (msg) => {
 if (msg.content.startsWith('>poll')) {
  if (msg.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return;
  const args = message.content
   .slice(prefix.length)
   .trim()
   .split(/ +/g);
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle('Poll!')
   .setColor('#0099ff')
   .setDescription(args[0]);
  await msg.channel.send(embed);
  await botMSG.react('');
  await botMSG.react('');
 }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Without any errors we can merely guess at the problem. So my guess would be that the user who tries to execute the command has Admin permissions. And because of your `if` statement, the code will stop if the user has Admin perms. However, there are two other issues I notice. You have `const args = message.content...` but where have you defined `message`? Same for `botMSG.react(...)`, where have you defined `botMSG`?

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `botMSG` change `await msg.channel.send(embed)` **to** `let botMSG = await msg.channel.send(embed)`